# Can a Mac App provide a Touch Bar while in the background?

Tags: macos, nstouchbar

Some Apple apps (such as Xcode and iTunes) add an item to the Control Strip on the Touch Bar that when selected shows the app's Touch Bar (e.g. Xcode's debugger and iTunes' scrubber) without bringing the app to the foreground.

Is it possible for a third party app to do something similar?

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605263/473672

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Spotify and TouchSwitcher do the same. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any open source program that you could look into.